# Is it possible to implement switch account feature using msal.js for SPA website?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-page-application, msal.js

I am trying to implement switch account feature for my SPA website. I am able to login an account that matches the current user that launched the browser. But if i prompt for account selection and provide a different account email id to login then it still using the current user that launched the browser to login and retrieves the id token. I have a service account that i would like to use but am not able to get token for the service user account from my actual windows account browser instance. Both of these accounts are in same tenant (company tenant) and i can log them in if i launch the browser (Run as User feature) with the corresponding windows Account. Is it possible to implement switch account using msal.js 1.2.2 version? if yes, can i get a sample on how to implement the feature?

The below is my msal config

```
var msalConfig = {
                auth: {
                    clientId: config.appServiceConfig.clientId,
                    authority: config.appServiceConfig.authority,
                    redirectURI: config.appServiceConfig.redirectURI,
                    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
                },
                cache: {
                    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
                    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
                }
            };
var requestObj = {
                    scopes: ["User.ReadBasic.All"],
                    prompt: "select_account",
                    loginHint: "serviceaccount@xxx.com",
                    authority: config.appServiceConfig.authority
                };
```

Appreciate any help!!!

Thanks
Sarat.

Comment: Please try to remove `loginHint` from requestObj. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request

Comment: @Sarat - This question has been acknowledged on https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1557. Please continue to follow the GitHub link for updates.